How to calculate the second order hyperpolarizability gamma using Gaussian16?
Dear StackExchange community,
I'm trying to calculate the second order hyperpolarizability gamma γ (for example mthane) in guassian16 using solvent introduced manuallly .
here is my input
%chk=methanegamma.chk
#  b3lyp/3-21g scrf=(solvent=generic,read,pcm) polar=(dcshg,cubic)

Title Card Required

    0 1
     C                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
     H                  0.63138400    0.63138400    0.63138400
     H                 -0.63138400   -0.63138400    0.63138400
     H                 -0.63138400    0.63138400   -0.63138400
     H                  0.63138400   -0.63138400   -0.63138400
    
       eps=2.274
       epsinf=2.244

I found this error:
Wanted a floating point number as input.
 Found a string as input.
    eps=2.274                                                                    
 ?
 Error termination via Lnk1e in C:\G09W\l101.exe at Wed Oct 23 10:46:23 2024.
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  0.0 seconds.

I dont understand where is the problem since the calculation of the first hyperpolarizability worked perfectly  with the same input file

Take a look here for the format/position required.

@Camps yes I respected the format. I did a bunch of calculations with this input(opt, TD, scan, polar) and it worked normaly , I dont know why its not working for gamma

Do you have the final blank line? What you posted in your question does not, along with having eps indented a lot (not sure if that's a problem, but it looks odd).

yes I have the blank line I just forgot to copy it. still not working
